# JQuery Autocomplete (older plug-in) list appears very small on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-autocomplete

I am using older JQuery Autocomplete plug-in (the one shown here - http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/). It is intended to be used for a Mobile app. The plug-in works just fine in the desktop browser. However, on the mobile device the plug-in list of auto-complete suggestions appears very, very small and is not readable at all.

I have tried to use "em" values for font-size and line-height in the CSS. Moreover, I have added this in the CSS -

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
```

But no luck! :(

I already have meta-viewport for my mobile app ad rest of the pages are just fine.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

As such, the JQuery plug-in seems to be working, because if I manage to click on one of those small rows - I am getting correct value in my text field. However, autocomplete list is too small to be readable and I am not able to figure out correct CSS to get this working. Any pointers/suggestions would be highly appreciated!

TIA,
- Manish

Comment: Interestingly, same code works fine in Mobile Firefox (7.0.1) and auto-complete list shows just fine in the browser. But it is not working in default web-kit safari browser (AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1) on my Android phone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it fixed now. It was rather subtle issue that was not obvious while fixing the problem. I did dig a lot and played a lot with CSS including some of the suggestions @sandeep mentioned here. However, none worked - with hard-coded "height" attribute in the css for each <li> element of JQuery div, I managed to make rows bigger for JQuery auto-complete list - but still the contents of those rows were not showing. However, when I tapped the row - correct value would be substituted in the text box. It was rather puzzling and suggested that probably the AppleWebKit browser was not rendering the contents.

The JQuery auto-complete list on the server had 3000+ <option> elements in it (we need different text for users and some short code for back-end), and AppleWebKit browser refused to show them as JQuery auto-complete rows (Firefox could show them without an issue), so finally I wrote small JS code for  **JQuery formatItem function** -

```
        //needed as option list is not shown by AppleWebKit safari browser
    formatItem: function(item, position, length, search){
        var name ="";       
        var str = "" + item;            
        var start = str.indexOf('">') + '">'.length;
        var end = str.lastIndexOf("</");
        name = str.substring(start,end);
        return name; 
    }
```

It extracts the label text of the option element and give it to JQuery auto-complete list.  This fixed the problem and I am able to use JQuery auto-complete properly now on the mobile devices. I have tested it with Android & iPhone (our target devices) and found that it works great on both of them!

**Solved!!** :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to define css property separately for the mobile device. For example :

```
@media all and (max-devide-width: 480px){
    .head{  
       width:200px;
           height:50px;
     } 
}
```

Comment: it's an example & may be you have to use !important for this

Comment: overriding you device css with mormal css use !important in device css may be that's work